# Leaving Job After New Hire and Before Boss Retires

Tags: resignation, new-hires, retirement

## The Questions:

Does anyone here have any advice for:

- Quitting shortly after a new hire (especially in a small team)
- Quitting shortly before your boss (who you deeply appreciate) retires
- The combination of the above two things

## The Story:

I work at a somewhat small company in Wisconsin. The company itself is about 700 people that are spread throughout the midwest, but the department that I work in is at the headquarters (100-200 people) in a smalltown (10-15k population) in Wisconsin. I only mention this because there is a "smalltown mindset" at this company, where they like to hire people who grew up in the area because then they will continue to live in the area and work for the same company their whole lives. So I think my coworkers and boss will be shocked when I quit - they probably subconsciously thought that I would work here for many more years, if not for my whole career. And to be fair, when I first took the job, that was an option that I was considering. But time has changed things for me and I now value leaving more than I value staying.

I love the people that I work with. I work in a small team of 5-7 people, 2 of us are programmers. They're all super nice, they've been super friendly and helpful, and they're easy to talk to about both work and non-work stuff. My boss has specifically been amazing. She doesn't micromanage, she communicates really well, she protects us from the onslaught of neverending projects, etc. Working for her has been a huge part of why I like my job.

At about June of last year, my wife and I started discussing the idea of me leaving my current job. We were both really interested in the idea, and we thought it would be a good choice - we just wanted to give ourselves some time to build up a stronger emergency fund, and to save for some expenses that we know will be coming up in the next year or so.

Well work has cranked up to a crazy level in the time since then. My company got a couple of new customers that are both individually far larger than our previous largest customer. So the number of projects on my teams list has become very long. My wife and I's requirements for our savings had been met by the end of October last year. However I didn't feel comfortable leaving at that time due to two reasons. First of those reasons is that one of my coworkers retired. The other programmer on my team decided he wanted to take the retired team member's position, and so he switched jobs. However he ended up covering both his old position and his new position for a while, and I know for a fact that he was working some long hours to make that work. That probably sounds terrible to some of you, but it's super rare in my team to need to do that - my manager tries to prevent it at all costs. I've only had to do it on a couple of days over the years. Anyways, the point of this is that I didn't want to abandon my already stressed and overworked teammate to handle all of the programming and his new position. The second reason I hadn't quit was because we were in the middle of one of our biggest projects yet. This is the reason my coworker had to work extra. There was just nothing we could do, we had to deliver on the project by a certain time or else there would be massive financial consequences. So I wanted to help get that project done before I would leave.

Well we're now mostly finished up on that big project. There's still some small issues, and miscellaneous reports to create, but the large bulk of it is done. In regards to filling in my programming teammate's shoes, we did finally hire a new grad a couple weeks ago.

However that brings up two new issues. First is that I am expected to help train in this new grad. I'm okay with this, but I don't want to keep delaying my resignation. I don't know what's socially acceptable. I think the smalltown mindset means that my coworkers will be pretty upset with me for "abandoning" the new hire. The second issue is that I found out that my boss is retiring soon. She doesn't have a firm date, but she said it would likely be near the end of April. So now I feel like I have to delay my resignation even more so that my boss doesn't have to deal with the stress of my resignation. But I don't want to delay it any longer, I had wanted to quit several months ago but I just stuck it out for a few months to help out my coworkers.

My wife and I talked about the idea of putting in my "6 weeks" instead of "2 weeks" to help provide a bigger buffer for the transition period for the new grad. I'm okay with this. However, this still wouldn't help with the retiring boss situation. I don't even know if it's considered rude to quit before your boss retires. I'm just assuming it is. I wasn't planning on that being the case, but it's what I've accidentally fallen into.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Joe. I will be looking for a new job eventually. The plan is that after quitting, I will be working on a few large house projects that will take up some time, as well as working on getting more experience with various programming related concepts that I have not had any experience with at my current job. Then once the house and coding projects are mostly finished, I will start looking for a new job.

Comment: I didn't go into much detail about this in my post, but I have a list of several reasons why I want to quit. The main problem, and source of several other problems, is that I am not happy with the direction that the company is headed. And now with the new knowledge that my boss will be retiring, I will likely be exposed to much more of the negative aspects of the company than I have been. I also want more exposure to different programming concepts - since there are only two programmers, my learning at this role has been limited to essentially teaching myself things online.

Comment: My wife makes enough to easily keep us afloat with her income alone, so we're not very worried about financials. I also have two different "fallback" jobs that I can rely on from friends and family, so in the event that I can't find a suitable job later this year, I can fallback on those jobs. They aren't ideal, but they would work great as a temporary solution (and technically I don't need those solutions anyways since my wife is happy to support us). So because of these reasons, I'm not very keen on the idea of a sabbatical - it's not completely out of the question, but I'd much rather quit.

Comment: Thank you @JoeStrazzere . I really appreciate your input!

Comment: Another "how do I quit" question that is identical to the dozens of other "how do I quit" questions on this site. Here's how: quit.

Answer (score 4):

You should be loyal to your company - as long as you are an employee. You can decide at any time that you want to stop being an employee. You find a new job, you give your notice, and that’s it. It has nothing to do with loyalty. You get paid to work there, you are not getting paid to stay longer than you want.

Comment: This kind of refrain is very common throughout this stack and while I think it's fine for most scenarios (especially in urban settings), it's not particularly appropriate for this querent's situation. The specific reasons for their departure don't relate to starting a new job; and the cultural expectations are different from those in an urban area. It doesn't offer a solution that won't cause sore feelings from the employer and potentially this manager that they really like.

Answer (score -1):

### Consider Switching to Very Limited Part-Time

Our company went through a similar situation a few years ago when one of our key employees elected to move on due to a litany of great reasons. While we were sad to see him go, we all understood his reasons for doing so.

The issue with his leaving is that he possessed a lot of technical knowledge, which nobody else in the company possessed. Similarly, he put in a 6 weeks notice and took some time to train myself and another person on this knowledge, but the opportunity to apply that knowledge didn't become possible for us for over a year after he'd left.

To mitigate this issue, my manager worked with him so that he could moonlight for us by remoting into our network and providing input on projects that fell within his expertise when it's needed (assuming he is available). Due to this arrangement, our company's former employee is able to make some extra money on the side when he has time and if he doesn't he simply informs us that he's not available to help.

I think in all, he might provide 2-4 hours a week at most.

You might consider determining if a similar proposal could work for yourself.

This allows you to assist in transferring your knowledge to the new graduates, while allowing you to focus on the goals that are most important to yourself. For the company side of things, they don't immediately lose the knowledge you possess, it just might take a lot longer to acquire. Plus, they generally can eliminate most of the overhead costs associated with a full-time employee.

If you do elect to go this route, it behooves you to inform your manager as soon as possible so that your company can make the effort to hire a replacement not just for your manager but also for yourself as well.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I am very open to this idea. However, I have my doubts that the company will want to pursue this route. I will definitely bring it up to my manager as an option that I am interested in when I resign. I think this option will also show some good faith on my end. Thank you again for your response.

Comment: @AwkwardQuestionsThrowaway you may want to hold off on proposing this idea to allow for some other answers to come in (it's only been a few hours since you posted). This answer is something that worked well for my company, but others might have a solution that will fit your situation better.

Comment: Thank you for the good advice. I won't be handing in my resignation until next week, so there will definitely be time for more responses to come in. I greatly appreciate your viewpoint.